# How to create a new database by Yii2 migration, when I have to use it by default?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, database-migration, yii2-advanced-app

I have a task which is described like "Creating a new database with Yii2 migration, and use it by default". But I have some collusion: I have to set up at lest one default database in my `main-local.php` file to start migration. But also I have to create this database with initial migration.

```
return [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=default_base',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
];
```

How can I deal with it? To create a database with migration and set up as default one.

When I execute my migration (there is code from my migration file):

```
public function safeUp()
{
    $this->execute("CREATE DATABASE default_base");
}
```

I have an exception:

```
General error: 1007 Can't create database 'default_base'; database exists
```

I realize that is because I have already created default_base in phpmyadmin (click button "created database"), and connected it with app in my `main-local.php` file. 
But I need this base to be created only when I execute `yii migrate`.

**UPD**

I have tried the way rob006 recommended but I get connection error

```
Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'default_base''
```

My main-local.php looks like the way exactly rob006 recommends, but I still can`t migrate. It works only if I set:

```
'preinstallDb' => [
                  'class'    => 'yii\db\Connection',
                  'dsn'      => 'mysql:host=localhost',
                  'username' => 'root',
                  'password' => '',
                  'charset'  => 'utf8',
            ],
            'db'           => [
                  'class'    => 'yii\db\Connection',
                  'dsn'      => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=already_exists_db',
                  'username' => 'root',
                  'password' => '',
                  'charset'  => 'utf8',
            ],
```

With the already exists database. What do I do wrong again?

Comment: You can [edit] your post by clicking the "edit" link in this comment or on the lower left side of the post. What is the problem you are facing: are you getting error messages, unexpected behavior or something else?

Comment: I updated it. I have an execution error, but I realize why it happened.

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer, instead of updating question. But your solution is brittle, since it will fail if you run `migrate` controller again.

Comment: You are right. I fixed it with 'IF NOT EXISTS' condition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define DSN without database name:

```
'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost',
```

And use this connection to create database.

```
Yii::$app->preinstallDb->createCommand('CREATE DATABASE default_base')->execute();
```

However you can't really create database in migration - `MigrateController` needs database for `migration` table to save migrations history. You would need to create database before `MigrateController` will try to access `migration` table. You can do this by overriding `MigrateController::getMigrationHistory()`:

```
class MigrateController extends \yii\console\controllers\MigrateController {

    protected function getMigrationHistory($limit) {
        Yii::$app->preinstallDb->createCommand('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS default_base')->execute();

        return parent::getMigrationHistory($limit);
    }
}
```

And use your controller in console app config:

```
'controllerMap' => [
    'migrate' => [
        'class' => MigrateController::class,
    ],
],
```

But honestly, it is ugly solution with a lot of hardcoding, it may be better to create some setup utility which will perform database creation outside of main app. Also usually for security reasons DB user used by application should not even have privileges to create database, so you may reconsider your use case - do you really need to create database by app?

Comment: hmm perks of being an official contributor, nice answer i never knew that +1.

Comment: Excellent and perfect.

Comment: Thank`s for the answer. I sure it has to work, but I still failed. Look please, I updated the question.

Comment: Are you sure you're using `Yii::$app->preinstallDb` in your migration?

Comment: Yes, I do.  Method safeUp looks like:  Yii::$app->preinstallDb->createCommand('CREATE DATABASE default_base')->execute();

Comment: Still nothing works. I decided to keep one default database created before migration

Comment: @ValikTralik "nothing works" does not really help to find the problem. Do you have any error message?

Comment: I have the same error 'Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'default_base'''

Answer (score 0):

I find the only way make it work for me. Just overriding init() in MigrateController.
First I added controllerMap in main-local.php file:

```
'controllerMap' => [
            'migrate' => [
                  'class' => 'console\controllers\MigrateController',]]
```

Then put new controller in console\controllers:

```
 namespace console\controllers;
use yii\console\controllers\MigrateController as BasicMigrateController;
use Yii;
class MigrateController extends BasicMigrateController
{
   public function init()
    {
       Yii::$app->preinstallDb->createCommand('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS default_base')->execute();
       parent::init();
    }
}
```